# Multiple CSV Automation - Distributors product feeds for ecommerce importing

Tags: magento2, import, csv

I am looking for a way to merge / automate 3 CSV files which each have different headings, i need to import these files automatically into Magento but they need to be mapped to attributes that Magento understands. At the moment this seems like an impossible task for me and i would hate the process of doing this every day or ever few hours to update stock etc.

My distributors generate the feeds every few hours and then it’s uploaded to my server. I need to find a way to achieve the above and to also get the file to import every few hours.

The only solution i have found at the moment is to use paid software like magento store manager but i do not need any of it just the one solution.

Comment: We offer another paid solution to make that possible, stand-alone extension without subscription https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html Another way can develop yourself and extend default M2 import, you can use our free version as base for that https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexport

Comment: I came across your extension about 10 minutes before you posting this! Thank you. I'll check it out now.